# Pulling records from a single table on match on one column and no match on other column

Tags: sql-server, select, join, null, operators

Pardon the title of question but this is what I have -

```
STAGING_CUST_ACCT(PARTY_KEY,NAME,TAX_ID,......)
```

Some sample data

```
1,John,234345
2,Tom,234345
1,Ken,000000
.
.
.
```

There are no constraints. I need to write a query to pull all party_keys which have different `party_key` but same `tax_id` and `tax_id` is not `NULL` or `blank`

```
select distinct a.party_key,a.tax_id from STAGING_CUST_ACCT a
join STAGING_CUST_ACCT b
on a.tax_id = b.tax_id
and a.party_key <> b.party_key
where ISNULL(a.tax_id,'')<>'' 
AND a.tax_id is not null
```

I did get results but I am not sure if the implementation of logic is correct. Can anybody please confirm/correct me if there is any easier way to write the above query?

Comment: The inequality join on party_key will return two rows for every pair of different keys. If you want just one row, try a greater-than or lesser-than comparison if you want just one row per difference.

Comment: Can you share some sample data so we know what you expect? Based on your description it looks like you don't need a join; you could just group on party key and tax id and filter missing tax ids

Comment: @Lain Elder - thanks for your response, I have added some sample data. In the above case I need both party keys 1 and 2 along with their name which share same tax_id (234345). Makes sense?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your where clause (including the and) seems uncecessary.  "JOIN" implies inner join where it will only include the records that match, nulls aren't joined on other nulls, so

```
select distinct a.party_key,a.tax_id 
from STAGING_CUST_ACCT a
inner join STAGING_CUST_ACCT b
    on a.tax_id = b.tax_id
    and a.party_key <> b.party_key
```

should give the same results (but you should probably confirm that :P)

EDIT oh and not blank missed that part

```
select distinct a.party_key,a.tax_id 
from STAGING_CUST_ACCT a
inner join STAGING_CUST_ACCT b
    on a.tax_id = b.tax_id
    and a.party_key <> b.party_key
    and a.tax_id <> ''
```

Comment: Thanks @Kritner . I am testing your query, but in the meanwhile, a quick question. Agreed that inner join won't join on nulls, but can it join on blank space?

Comment: I think I will still need ISNULL(a.tax_id,'')<>'' in my where condition since it did join on '' :)

Answer (score 0):

```
select count(*), a.party, a.tax_id 
from STAGING_CUST_ACCT a
join STAGING_CUST_ACCT b
on a.tax_id = b.tax_id
GROUP By a.party, a.tax_id
Having count(*) = 1
where a.tax_id is not null
```

Comment: While this answer may answer the question, the explanation may significantly improve the acceptance and understanding of the solution. Consider to add more details to your answer. Thanks!